# Plotting multiple lines in on a shapefile in R

Tags: r

I am very not familiar with programming and I just started using R
I am trying to plot several lines in a shape file using the code below (only 2 line with start and end coordinates are used as an example here).

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

lat1<- c(-0.755488889, -0.724580556)
long1<- c(36.44060833, 36.43528056)
latlon1<- cbind(lat1,long1)
crdref <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
lns1_YGLV <- spLines(latlon1, crs=crdref)
lns1_YGLV
plot(lns1_YGLV)

lat2<- c(-0.8396,   -0.735166667)
long2<- c(36.362475, 36.59591667)
latlong2<- cbind(lat2,long2)
crdref <- CRS('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84')
lns2_SUGT <- spLines(latlong2, crs=crdref)
lns2_SUGT
plot(lns2_SUGT)

N<- shapefile("path\\file.shp")
plot(N)
```

(file path and name of shape files edited just to make it simple.)

However,this whole code keeps plotting only one line, but if I run the code individually, it plots well, and the shapefile and the two lines plot separately and differently. What could i be doing wrong, please help!

Comment: Is it possible you have a shapefile that is not having similar bounds to the location of your lines? Point us to an accessible version of this shapefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the coordinates of the shapefile are congruent with the lines you have constructed then I *suspect* (but it is a guess) that you need to first plot the shapefile with:

```
 plot(N)
```

And then use the add=TRUE parameter which allows overlaying:

```
 plot(lns1_YGLV, add=TRUE )
 plot(lns2_SUGT, add=TRUE )
```

There is also be a `lines` method for `Raster*` objects. See http://127.0.0.1:21396/library/raster/html/plot.html . There is also a `Note` on that page warning Windows users: "raster uses rasterImage from the graphics package. For unknown reasons this does not work on Windows Server and on a few versions of Windows XP. On that system you may need to use argument useRaster=FALSE to get a plot."